# Passing Dynamic Data to Bootstrap Modal Angular 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of objects that I am am passing information from to a bootstrap modal. Modal looks like this:

```
  <button
class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
data-toggle="modal"
data-target="#matchModal"
(click)="matchSearch()">
Select</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="matchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
 labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
  label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Card Matches</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let matchBrandCard of matchBrandCards">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
        <li>{{matchBrandCard.title}}</li>
        <li>{{matchBrandCard.uuid}}</li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Create</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Merge</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
 dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update
In my component:

```
matchBrandCards: Card[] = [];

matchSearch() {
this.clientCardsService.fetchBrandCards(this.clientCards.title).subscribe(
  clientCards => {
    this.matchBrandCards = clientCards;
  }
);
```

}

clientCards is the list that provides the necessary parameters for my http request to then create matchBrandCards.

My problem is that the information gets passed to the modal the first time correctly but when I select other items from the list, the modal does not update with the new selected information. Everything is working with updating the matchBrandCards that I iterate over to create the list in the modal but the displayed values stay the same. Looking for a way to achieve my desired functionality.

Suggestions || tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are yo updating your modal data?

Comment: modal data is coming from http request that I am assigning to matchBrandCards

Comment: Are you able to post the code for how you declare and update your matchBrandCards variable?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `matchBrandCards` to a subject and use `async`:

```
  <div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let matchBrandCard of matchBrandCards$ | async">
```

in the containing component:

```
public matchBrandCards$ = new Subject();
```

and then when you have an update:

```
updateHandler(values) {
  this.matchBrandCards$.next(values);
}
```

Comment: matchBrandCards already has a type tied to it that goes with my backend data.

Comment: I understand that, so either change it and load the BE data into an observable, or define another observable that accepts the data on each update